# Not able to get file using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, file-upload, formik

I am using formik in my react component. one such element is file.

```
                                          <td>
                                            <div className="mb-10">
                                                <label
                                                    id="attachedFilesLabel"
                                                    className="required form-label" >
                                                    Attached files
                                                </label>
                                                <Field
                                                    type="file"
                                                    className="form-control
                                                    multiple
                                                    placeholder="files"
                                                    name="attachedFile"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
```

when I print it using `alert` ,  `alert('values:'+inputParams.attachedFile);`

[image]

if I print `inputParams.attachedFile[0]` or `inputParams.attachedFile[0].file` it comes as `undefined`.

how can I get `file` instead of `filename` so that I can send the same to API.

when I am printing `payload` then it is coming as `filename` instead of file it is printing `file path`.

[image]

Comment: Can anybody help me on the same?

Answer (score 2):

Because `formik` does not support for uploading file , you should do something like this :

```
<Field  type="file" onChange={(event) => {
  setFieldValue("file", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
}} />
```

Then get the file on form submit  :

```
     onSubmit={(values) => {
           console.log(values.file)
           }
     }
```

Comment: thanks. now file is coming as empty as {}.